# sending a £ symbol via IE to Twitter via ?status=xyz (unicode error)

Tags: php, twitter, urlencode

Got a link that allows a user to share a message to their twitter followers.
The URL contains a £ sound which twitter complains about when clicked from IE but works fine in FireFox.

Any advise please?

Thanks

Comment: How is that `£` encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pound sign must be URL encoded, all non-ASCII and even some ASCII characters have to be encoded in order to be passed via the GET protocol (or a URL).

the pound sign is %C2%A3

Comment: @PHPology If you're writing PHP code to handle any URL then you will need to use urlencode to encode the characters, but also wrap it in a UTF-8 compatible function (since urlencode is not UTF-8 compatible).  there are user posted functions on http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php that might do the job for you.